# Sql-Data purging on the basis of datetime column in the table having 10+ million rows

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am working with SQL Server 2012, I have a table with approx 35 column and 10+ million rows. Now I want to do the data purging on the basis of datetime stamp and other various filter.

The sample data is as below

```
ID  DateTimeStamp               value1  value2   value3 .... Value 35
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2   2016-07-26 15:12:41 0.00    126.20  328051.07
2   2016-07-26 15:14:41 0.00    126.20  328051.07
2   2016-07-26 15:18:17 0.00    126.14  328052.32
2   2016-07-26 15:23:17 0.00    126.75  328054.40
2   2016-07-26 15:24:34 0.00    126.75  328054.40
2   2016-07-26 15:25:18 0.00    126.75  328054.40
2   2016-07-26 15:28:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
2   2016-07-26 15:29:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
2   2016-07-26 15:30:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
2   2016-07-26 15:34:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
```

I want to do the data purging on the basis of time interval, Let’s say if  I select the time interval of 5 minutes my expected result set should be as below

```
ID  DateTimeStamp               value1  value2   value3 .... Value 35
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2   2016-07-26 15:12:41 0.00    126.20  328051.07
2   2016-07-26 15:18:17 0.00    126.14  328052.32
2   2016-07-26 15:23:17 0.00    126.75  328054.40
2   2016-07-26 15:28:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
2   2016-07-26 15:34:15 0.00    126.95  328060.64
```

It should happen in such way that if the required datetime stamp is not exist the most closest value (Previous or next, whichever is most closest should be considered.  )

Though I have achieved it with below logic (pseudo code), but it's extremely slow

```
While(1)
begin
    StartDate = Start date of data purging at first iteration latter on assign it to EndDate in all next iteration 

    EndDate = EndDate + Interval
    NextEndDate  = EndDate + Interval

    Set maxDateTime = Select top(1) * 
                      from <TableName> 
                      where dateTime between StartDate to End Date  
                      order by datetime asc

    Set minDateTime = Select top(1) * 
                      from <TableName> 
                      where dateTime between EndDate to End NextEndDate 
                      order by datetime desc

    Now compare difference and choose the one which is smaller.  
        Diff(maxDateTime, EndDateTime) & Diff (minDateTime, EndDateTime)
end
```

Can anyone suggest the efficient approach for the above logic

Comment: Does your expected result show the rows you want to keep, not purge? Your pseudo code looks to be trying to identify the row closest to the midpoint of each interval but the expect result seem to show the row closest to the start of each interval. It will be more efficient to identify the row closest to the start.

Comment: Yeah, the expected result is something i want to keep and remaining to purge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is an example that deletes all but the first row within each 5-minute interval. This method uses a loop for each interval to improve concurrency and avoid filling the transaction log, although it could be done as a single set-based operation using a tally table (or CTE) to calculate intervals if those are not concerns for you.

It is important to have an index (ideally clustered) with `DateTimeStamp` as the leftmost key column to improve performance.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableName(
      ID  int NOT NULL
    , DateTimeStamp datetime2(0) NOT NULL
    , value1 decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
    , value2 decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
    , value3 decimal(18,2) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TableName VALUES
     (2, '2016-07-26 15:12:41', 0.00, 126.20, 328051.07)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:14:41', 0.00, 126.20, 328051.07)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:18:17', 0.00, 126.14, 328052.32)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:23:17', 0.00, 126.75, 328054.40)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:24:34', 0.00, 126.75, 328054.40)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:25:18', 0.00, 126.75, 328054.40)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:28:15', 0.00, 126.95, 328060.64)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:29:15', 0.00, 126.95, 328060.64)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:30:15', 0.00, 126.95, 328060.64)
    ,(2, '2016-07-26 15:34:15', 0.00, 126.95, 328060.64);
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx ON dbo.TableName(DateTimeStamp);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
      @StartDateTimeStamp datetime2(0)
    , @LastDateTimeStamp datetime2(0)
    , @EndDateTimeStamp datetime2(0)
    , @IntervalSeconds int = 300;
SET @StartDateTimeStamp = (SELECT MIN(DateTimeStamp) FROM dbo.TableName);
SET @LastDateTimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(DateTimeStamp) FROM dbo.TableName);

WHILE @StartDateTimeStamp <= @LastDateTimeStamp
BEGIN
    SET @EndDateTimeStamp = DATEADD(second, @IntervalSeconds, @StartDateTimeStamp);

    WITH rows_to_delete AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DateTimeStamp) AS row_num
        FROM dbo.TableName
        WHERE 
            DateTimeStamp >= @StartDateTimeStamp
            AND DateTimeStamp < @EndDateTimeStamp
        )
    DELETE rows_to_delete
    WHERE row_num > 1;

    SET @StartDateTimeStamp = DATEADD(second, @IntervalSeconds, @StartDateTimeStamp);
END;
GO
```

Comment: let me give it a try ,I will be get back to you shortly

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dan Guzman It Works For me and performance of query is best .